# Java Swing: Combine RowFilter.andFilter with RowFilter.orFilter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I couldn't quite get this to work, and the examples I found only worked with a single RowFilter.andFilter or a RowFilter.orFilter.  Is there a way to combine two to get something like (A || B) && (C || D)?  Below is some sample code of what I'm attempting.

```
ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>> arrLstColorFilters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>();
ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>> arrLstCandyFilters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>();
RowFilter<Object,Object> colorFilter;
RowFilter<Object,Object> candyFilter;
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

// OR colors
RowFilter<Object,Object> blueFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter("Blue", myTable.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("Color"));
RowFilter<Object,Object> redFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter("Red", myTable.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("Color"));
arrLstColorFilters.add(redFilter);
arrLstColorFilters.add(blueFilter);
colorFilter = RowFilter.orFilter(arrLstColorFilters);

// OR candies
RowFilter<Object,Object> mAndMFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter("M&M", myTable.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("Candy"));
RowFilter<Object,Object> mentosFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter("Mentos", myTable.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("Candy"));
arrLstCandyFilters.add(mAndMFilter);
arrLstCandyFilters.add(mentosFilter);
candyFilter = RowFilter.orFilter(arrLstCandyFilters);

// Mentos and M&Ms that are red or blue (this is where I'm stuck)
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(candyFilter, colorFilter);  //this does not work
```

If someone could provide a working snippet for what I'm trying to do in the last line, it'd be much appreciated.  Currently maintaining two separate table models to circumvent this problem, and I'd like to avoid duplicating data.

Thanks,
Kai

Comment: Maybe if you posted a "unworking snippet" with real data then someone will be able to create a "working snippet".  We don't know what your real data looks like so its kind of hard to create and test any code.

Comment: I guess it's more of a syntax question.  You can create RowFilter.orFilter and RowFilter.andFilter separately in the api doc:
  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#andFilter%28java.lang.Iterable%29
  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#orFilter%28java.lang.Iterable%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your last line doesn't even compile, because `andFilter` also requires a list instead of separate arguments.

Otherwise your example seem to work find in my tests. I replaced the last line in your example with the following code:

```
ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>> andFilters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>();
andFilters.add(candyFilter);
andFilters.add(colorFilter);

sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(myTable.getModel());

// Mentos and M&Ms that are red or blue
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(andFilters));

myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Please make sure that you initialize the TableRowSorter with the appropriate table model.

Comment: Yes, you're right, another intermediate arraylist.  Seems a little more verbose to need that, but, yes, that's what the API says...  Thank you for your help.